# Finding an angle of a triangle in the upper half plane model given three points

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

I've been given three points in the upper half plane $(i, 3i, 1 + 2i$), and one of the homework questions that asked is to find the angles of the given triangle. A previous problem asks to find the length of the sides of the triangle, and then I'm also asked to find the measure of the angles of the triangle. Would they relate? if they do not, how would I find the angles?

Comment: Hi, leinaudGnus, and welcome to Math.SE!  It appears the points you ask about are in the complex plane, and they form a triangle (as they do not lie in a common line).  I'd help to improve your wording, but I notice that the tag for hyperbolic-geometry was chosen by you.  Is there an issue about hyperbolic geometry here, or is it simply plane geometry?

Comment: Is the the Euclidean complex plane, or hyperbolic plane?  I see they hyperbolic geometry tag, but it doesn't say hyperbolic in the question.

Comment: Given that he talks about the triangle living in the upper half plane, and specifically calls it the upper half plane **model** in the title, it's safe to assume he's talking about hyperbolic geometry here.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the geodesics in the upperhalf plane model of hyperbolic geometry, $H$, are semicircles centered on the real line and vertical straight lines with constant real value. Try to find the circular/vertical arcs/line segments which connect your three points.

Another point you might like to recall is that the upperhalf plane model of hyperbolic geometry actually preserves angles from the Euclidean geometry of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. This means that if you can find the angles of the triangle at the point of intersection in the euclidean case, with the same curved edges *, then the angles will be the same in the hyperbolic case, and so you're done. Note that in hyperbolic geometry, there exist triangles with zero angles (although any such vertices with zero angle lie on the boundary of $H$, so don't apply to this problem).

My biggest tip I can give you for solving this problem is to draw pictures!

*** if a curve intersects another curve, their angle of intersection is the difference between the angles of straight lines tangent to the curves at their point of intersection

Comment: i found that the angles in euclidean space were pi/4, pi/4 and pi/2. according to the area of a triangle in the upper half plane model, A= pi - a + b + c, where a, b, and c are the angles of the triangle. however, that makes the area = 0. is there something that i did wrong?

Comment: When i say in the Euclidean case, I mean the same curves in $H$ which give the hyperbolic triangle (so in your case 2 arcs of a semi-circle and a vertical line segment) but you measure the angles as you normally would in the Euclidean case, by comparing the tangent lines at the intersection of two curves.

Answer (score 0):

... just wanted to see what happens, when a ten years plus old question gets an other answer. The question was found while answering an other question on hyperbolic geometry, also connected with computer algebra usage in such situation, in particular [sage](https://www.sagemath.org), so the results will be checked also with sage.

---

The picture of the triangle with vertices $i$, $3i$, $1+2i$ is as follows:

[image: mse 375727]

Only the part in the upper half plane $\Bbb H$ should be considered. The sides of the hyperbolic triangle are:

- the (euclidean) arc from $i$ to $1+2i$ on the circle centered in $2$ with radius $\sqrt{1^2+2^2}=\sqrt 5$,
- the (euclidean) arc from $1+2i$ to $3i$ on the circle centered in $-2$ with radius $\sqrt{3^2+2^2}=\sqrt {13}$,
- the (euclidean) segment from $3i$ to $i$ on the ray $Oy$.

The angles of the hyperbolic triangle can be also extracted from the euclidean picture, we draw tangents to the hyperbolic geodesics (two semicircles, and one line in the euclidean world), and measure in the euclidean world the angle between them. Note that if an angle $\alpha$ is equal to $\arctan t$, so $t=\tan\alpha$, then $\cos^2 \alpha =\frac 1{1+t^2}$, $\sin^2 \alpha =\frac {t^2}{1+t^2}$.

- For instance the marked angle in $1+2i$ can be computed in the euclidean world from the euclidean triangle with vertices $1+2i$, $7i/2$, $3i/2$. The tangent for the angle in $3i/2$ is (reading it in the triangle with other two vertices $0,-3$) equal to $3/(3/2)=2$. The tangent for the angle in $7i/2$ is (reading it in the triangle with other two vertices $1+2i,2i$) equal to $1/(3/2)=2/3$. So the marked angle in $1+2i$ is:
  $$
  \pi - \left(\arctan 2+\arctan \frac 23\right) 
  =-\arctan\frac{2+\frac 23}{1-2\cdot \frac 23}
  =\arctan 8
  =\arccos\frac 1{\sqrt {65}}
  =\arcsin\frac 8{\sqrt {65}}
  \approx 82.8749836510982\dots
  \ .
  $$
- In a similar manner we compute the angle in $3i$ from the euclidean triangle with two other vertices in $0$, $9/2$, so this angle is
  $$
  \arctan \frac 32
  =\arccos\frac 2{\sqrt{13}}
  =\arcsin\frac 3{\sqrt{13}}
  \approx 56.309932474020\dots\ .
  $$
- And in $i$, using the euclidean triangle with vertices in $0$, $-1/2$, it is
  $$
  \arctan\frac 12
  =\arccos\frac 2{\sqrt5}
  =\arcsin\frac 1{\sqrt5}
  \approx 26.565051177078\dots\ .
  $$
  $\square$

---

There is indeed a connection between the angles and the sides, the [hyperbolic law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_law_of_cosines#Hyperbolic_laws_of_cosines). The side $a$, opposed to the angle $A$ in a hyperbolic triangle with sides $a,b,c$, and angles $A,B,C$ is thus given by:
$$
a =\operatorname{arccosh} \frac {\cos A+\cos B\cos C}{\sin B\sin C}\ .
$$
Alternative formula for the hyperbolic distance
between the points $z,w$ is
$$
\operatorname{arccosh} \left(1+\frac{|z-w|^2}{2\Im z\Im w}\right)\ .
$$
So we compute for the length of one of the sides as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cosh \operatorname{distance}(i, 3i)
&=\frac
{\frac1{\sqrt{65}} + \frac 2{\sqrt {13}}\cdot\frac 2{\sqrt 5}}
{ \frac 3{\sqrt {13}}\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt 5}}
=\frac {1+2\cdot 2}{3\cdot 1}=\frac 53\ ,\qquad\text{ or alternatively}
\\
\cosh \operatorname{distance}(i, 3i)
&=1+\frac{|3i-i|^2}{2\cdot 1\cdot 3}=1 + \frac 23=\frac 53\ ,
\\[3mm]
\cosh \operatorname{distance}(i, 1+2i)
&=\frac
{\frac 2{\sqrt {13}} + \frac1{\sqrt{65}}\cdot\frac 2{\sqrt 5}}
{ \frac 8{\sqrt {65}}\cdot\frac 1{\sqrt 5}}
=\frac {2+\frac 25}{\frac 85}=\frac {12}8=\frac 32\ ,\qquad\text{ or alternatively}
\\
\cosh \operatorname{distance}(i, 1+2i)
&=1+\frac{|1+2i-i|^2}{2\cdot 1\cdot 2}=1 + \frac 12=\frac 32\ ,
\\[3mm]
\cosh \operatorname{distance}(3i, 1+2i)
&=\frac
{\frac 2{\sqrt 5} + \frac1{\sqrt{65}}\cdot \frac 2{\sqrt {13}}}
{ \frac 8{\sqrt {65}}\cdot\frac 3{\sqrt {13}}}
=\frac {2+\frac 2{13}}{\frac {24}{13}}
=\frac {28}{24}=\frac 76\ ,\qquad\text{ or alternatively}
\\
\cosh \operatorname{distance}(3i, 1+2i)
&=1+\frac{|1+2i-3i|^2}{2\cdot 3\cdot 2}=1 + \frac 16=\frac 76\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

*Computer check:* We can check the above in the following manner:

```
H = HyperbolicPlane().UHP()
A, B, C = H.get_point(i), H.get_point(3*i), H.get_point(1 + 2*i)

AB = H.get_geodesic(A, B)
BC = H.get_geodesic(B, C)
CA = H.get_geodesic(C, A)
```

With the above definitions we can now ask for:

```
sage: AB.length()
arccosh(5/3)

sage: BC.length()
arccosh(7/6)

sage: CA.length()
arccosh(3/2)

sage: AB.angle(BC)
arccos(2/13*sqrt(13))

sage: BC.angle(CA).simplify_full()
pi - arccos((sqrt(13) - 3)/(3*sqrt(13)*sqrt(5) - 13*sqrt(5)))
sage: bool( BC.angle(CA) == arccos(1/sqrt(65)) )
True

sage: CA.angle(AB)
arccos(2/5*sqrt(5))
```